# Best way to make a list of a specified length of binaries with a specified number of True members

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to make a list of x zeroes and y ones in random locations. It feels like this should be doable in Mathematica in a very few characters, but my solution (which works perfectly) is relatively verbose.

I'm here using 0 and 1 rather than False and True.

```
exactlyNOnes[n_Integer, outOf_Integer] := Module[{list, rands},
   list = Table[0, outOf];
   While[Total[list] < n, 
    list = ReplacePart[list, RandomInteger[outOf - 1] + 1 -> 1]];
   list
   ];
```

I'm curious to know how wiser people would solve this.

Comment: You could use [`RandomSample`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomSample), something like: ``RandomSample @ Join[ConstantArray[1, n], ConstantArray[0, m]]``.

Comment: @CarlWoll That's the most elegant solution here. If you make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a (comparison of two) solutions for relatively small `x+y`, that I can think of.

```
x = 7; (* seven ones *)
y = 2; (* two zeros *)
```

Generate an exhaustive list and `Select` (36 cases):

```
alist = IntegerDigits[#, 2, x + y] &@Range[0, 2^(x + y) - 1];
res1 = Select[Count[#, 1] == x && Count[#, 0] == y &][alist]
```

> {{0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1,
> 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
> 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,    1},
> {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0,    1,
> 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 1,    0,
> 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,    1},
> {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1,    0,
> 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1,    1,
> 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,    0},
> {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1,    1,
> 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 1,    1,
> 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,    1},
> {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1,    1,
> 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1,    0,
> 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,    0},
> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}}

---

The other solution is based on `Subsets` and using `ReplacePart` for direct replacements:

```
replacements = Thread[# -> 0] & /@ Subsets[Range[x + y], {y}]

res2 = ReplacePart[ConstantArray[1, x + y], #] & /@ replacements // 
  Sort

res1 == res2
```

> True